# Wordpress "white screen of death" on new posts and pages

Tags: php, wordpress

Developing a new site. I'm getting the white-screen-of-death every time I try to create a new page or post. I've deactivated all plugins, changed themes and tried 3 different versions of the wordpress core (6.0.2, 6.0.1, 5.9.8) to try and find a solution - nothing's working and all was fine yesterday. The error showing on the server logs is:

> PHP Warning:  Creating default object from empty value in /public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 742.

Can anyone suggest a solution? Is it an issue with the host server? Surely I've circumvented problems with the install by trying all of the above. I'm open to ideas.

Comment: Line 742 is here, for the latest WordPress 6.0.2. https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.0.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L742 Is your report from some earlier version?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to "reset" the `.htaccess` file? Sometimes the white screen is solved by doing this.

This should be in `.htaccess` inside the `public_html` folder.:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Also, can you share what's in `/public_html/wp-admin/includes/post.php on line 742`?

Comment: Line 742 is:
 $post->post_content = (string) apply_filters( 'default_content', $post_content, $post );